# UIImage resize (Scale proportion)

Tags: iphone, resize, uiimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize UIImage with aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio)

The following piece of code is resizing the image perfectly, but the problem is that it messes up the aspect ratio (resulting in a skewed image). Any pointers?

```
// Change image resolution (auto-resize to fit)
+ (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toResolution:(int)resolution {
    CGImageRef imgRef = [image CGImage];
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    //if already at the minimum resolution, return the orginal image, otherwise scale
    if (width <= resolution && height <= resolution) {
        return image;

    } else {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;

        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = resolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        } else {
            bounds.size.height = resolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageCopy;
}
```

Comment: See this question (and my answer ;): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio/1703210#1703210

Comment: Links to other SO questions aren't really considered great answers. If this is a duplicate, it should be closed as such.

Comment: This helped me with an issue where I needed to scale an UIImage, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change worked for me:

```
// The size returned by CGImageGetWidth(imgRef) & CGImageGetHeight(imgRef) is incorrect as it doesn't respect the image orientation!
// CGImageRef imgRef = [image CGImage];
// CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
// CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
//
// This returns the actual width and height of the photo (and hence solves the problem
CGFloat width = image.size.width; 
CGFloat height = image.size.height;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 122):

I used this single line of code to create a new UIImage which is scaled. Set the scale and orientation params to achieve what you want. The first line of code just grabs the image.

```
    // grab the original image
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    // scaling set to 2.0 makes the image 1/2 the size. 
    UIImage *scaledImage = 
                [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] 
                              scale:(originalImage.scale * 2.0)
                                 orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
```

Comment: This is a logical resize. If you are looking to resize an image for performance purposes have a look at http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/ or even at http://eran.sandler.co.il/2011/11/07/uiimage-in-ios-5-orientation-and-resize/ if you experience a wrong behaviour in iOS 5.

Comment: clearly it is Abdul or 36 people wouldn't have up voted. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: scaling to 2.0 makes the image 1/2 the size...LOL!

Comment: for swift:             `let img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "lena")!`
            `var scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: img.CGImage!, scale: img.scale * 2, orientation: img.imageOrientation)`

Comment: @zonabi, it's not so funny. What about dividing by 2.0 instead of multiplying... `UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:image.scale/2.0 orientation:(image.imageOrientation)];` This way you get a more logical presentation of your scale desire (aka "I want to multiply scale with a n factor")

Answer (score 17):

That's ok not a big problem . thing is u got to find the proportional width and height

like if size is  2048.0 x 1360.0 which has to be resized to 320 x 480 resolution then the resulting image size should be  722.0 x 480.0

```
here is the formulae to do that . if w,h is original and x,y are resulting image.
w/h=x/y 
=> 
x=(w/h)*y;  

submitting w=2048,h=1360,y=480 => x=722.0 ( here width>height. if height>width then consider x to be 320 and calculate y)
```

U can submit in this web page . [ARC](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/)

Confused ? alright ,  here is category for UIImage which will do the thing for you.

```
@interface UIImage (UIImageFunctions)
    - (UIImage *) scaleToSize: (CGSize)size;
    - (UIImage *) scaleProportionalToSize: (CGSize)size;
@end
@implementation UIImage (UIImageFunctions)

- (UIImage *) scaleToSize: (CGSize)size
{
    // Scalling selected image to targeted size
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

    if(self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight)
    {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -size.height, 0.0f);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.height, size.width), self.CGImage);
    }
    else
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

    CGImageRef scaledImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: scaledImage];

    CGImageRelease(scaledImage);

    return image;
}

- (UIImage *) scaleProportionalToSize: (CGSize)size1
{
    if(self.size.width>self.size.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"LandScape");
        size1=CGSizeMake((self.size.width/self.size.height)*size1.height,size1.height);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Potrait");
        size1=CGSizeMake(size1.width,(self.size.height/self.size.width)*size1.width);
    }

    return [self scaleToSize:size1];
}

@end
```

-- the following is appropriate call to do this if img is the UIImage instance.

img=[img scaleProportionalToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];

Comment: Do you mean anImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;?

Comment: yup similar to content Mode but not using any UI elements thus scaled image can further be stored into file or db...

Answer (score 5):

This fixes the math to scale to the max size in both width and height rather than just one depending on the width and height of the original.

```
- (UIImage *) scaleProportionalToSize: (CGSize)size
{
    float widthRatio = size.width/self.size.width;
    float heightRatio = size.height/self.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        size=CGSizeMake(self.size.width*heightRatio,self.size.height*heightRatio);
    } else {
        size=CGSizeMake(self.size.width*widthRatio,self.size.height*widthRatio);
    }

    return [self scaleToSize:size];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the `bounds`'s size integer.

```
#include <math.h>
....

    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = resolution;
        bounds.size.height = round(bounds.size.width / ratio);
    } else {
        bounds.size.height = resolution;
        bounds.size.width = round(bounds.size.height * ratio);
    }
```