# How can I make the large image into small with as good quality as the original image?

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview

I am using imagview with size of 80X80 to display large image (1024 X 780).

While placing the large image into the imageview, the image looks squeezed, compressed something not like the quality one.

My question is, how can I make the large image into small with as good quality as the original image ?

Answer (score 1):

In the image view, please make the **imageview.mode** as **centre** not **scale to fit** or any other.
I believe this would put ur any scaled image at **finest quality** in ur 80x80 dimension.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should do proper Scaling of the Image that u want to show in the ImageView

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize 
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = chosenImage;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) 
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor*1;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage ;
}
```

Comment: than q surya this coding is usefull my concept

Answer (score 1):

`[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];`

You should however consider resizing the image and saving it on the disk if you want to use it more then once.
To resize the image:

[The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

[UIImage resize (Scale proportion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645768/uiimage-resize-scale-proportion)

[UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)

etc..

Comment: than q surya this coding is usefull my concept

Answer (score 0):

Going from 1034x780 into 80x80 is virtually impossible to keep the quality, as there isn't enough space to capture all the details.

You can try to scale it:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: This works, but in iOS5.0.1 its causing a memory leak. Is there an alternative approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236837/memory-leak-drawinrect-on-ios5-0-1

Answer (score 0):

you can set image mode `[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];`

    imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight );
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];