# Changing image size in iOS5

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a problem resizing images from web service (in code below i'm trying to get 400*266 down to 300*200). In detail view controller's viewDidLoad I add scroll view and image view. Then I add image to image view and change the size of image view's frame. Result is 300*100 image. Height is always about half of what I want. But if I change dimensions manually in storyboard (not useful for different image dimensions) it works like a charm. What am I missing?

```
@interface DetailVIewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
....    

//adding image and resizing imageview's frame
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURL]]];
imageView.image = image;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 200);
....

//further down the code (if it's an issue):
CGSize size = {screenWidth, screenHeight};
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.contentSize = size;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have images with different dimensions, then you need to look at in concept of scale rather than dimension. You adjust the scale of the image as you initialize it, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679267/442328). Then you when you set the image to the imageView call `[imageView sizeToFit]` to make it as fit exactly as the image size.

hope this helps.

Comment: weird...this didn't help either. actualy,the bigger number i enter for scale, closer to square my picture gets :/ i tried this: 

UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURL]]];
// scaling set to 2.0 makes the image 1/2 the size. 
UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

even if i enter dimensions in code,image doesn't seem to follow my instructions.any other ideas?

Comment: well scaling to 2.0 makes hte image double the size. You need to scale to 0.5.

Comment: maybe any other suggestion on scaling image size down to little less than screen width (300px)?

Comment: actually it makes it half the size.tried it.bigger the number,smaller the image.

Comment: well... thats wierd. you can play around with the scale factor to get the size you want.. are you still calling `self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 200)` ? you need to get rid of that if you are using `sizeToFit`.

Comment: i commented it out now when i have size to fit. tried this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio/1703210#1703210) with no luck.if i scale down enough i get a square :/

Comment: found the problem.tab bar and navigation bar.when i copied my code (tried also all possible solutions) to fresh project it all works great (including suggested solutions).when i embed in navigation controller image loses in height, if i add tabs it loses some more height (without touching the code which manages size).is this line `CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` the problem when using navigation or tab bar?

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly solved the problem. I clicked on *MainStoryboard.storyboard* and I fiddled with it a bit. When I unchecked *Resize View From NIB* ... vuola ... image was perfect size :D

(click on view controller in storyboard -> Attributes Inspector -> View Controller -> Layout -> Resize View From NIB)