# Is there any difference between CGImageGetWidth(workingImage.CGImage) and workingImage.size.width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, quartz-graphics

Is there any difference between `CGImageGetWidth(workingImage.CGImage)` and `workingImage.size.width` ? Is the first faster or safer? I know that in the second case I get the value directly.

Comment: Is `workingImage.size.width` even legal for an `CGImageRef` opaque type?

Comment: In both cases all is ok.

Comment: How though?  `CGImageRef` is **not** an object!  Some sort of bridging?  If so, there's a difference.

Comment: `workingImage = [ProcessHelper convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:rawData
                                                    withWidth:CGImageGetWidth(workingImage.CGImage)
                                                   withHeight:CGImageGetHeight(workingImage.CGImage)];`

Comment: So `workingImage` is a `UIImage`?  Why didn't you mention that?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. But my questin is: is differenct between first and second case?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of your `ProcessHelper` class. In general the width and height of a `UIImage` will match those of the underlying `CGImage`. If the scale factor of the image is set other than `1.0` though, they'll differ by that factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually both of them returns the same result. `CGImageGetWidth(Image.CGImage)` returns the Bitmap image width, `Image.size.width` returns the UIImage width. If you ask about safe/fast, i think first one will be faster, because it comes from **ApplicationServices** framework and the second one is from **UIKit** framework. Hope this helps you..

Comment: You mean one's implemented in C++ and the other in Objective-C?

Comment: Apple uses C in this (and most non-Objective-C) case(s), not C++.

Comment: No, they do not always return the same result! I've just resized a UIImage with methods described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645768/uiimage-resize-scale-proportion , and found out that CGImageGetWidth(Image.CGImage) will return the width of the original image, not the resized width. Image.size.width however returns the scaled width.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `image` is a `UIImage *`, `CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage)` returns the width in pixels, whereas `image.size.width` returns the width in screen coordinates, i.e. the pixel width divided by the `image.scale`, which is typically the scale factor for the current display (2 on most Retina devices, 3 on iPhone 6 Plus), although it may be any arbitrary value, depending on how the image was created.

In terms of performance, I expect they are both ~ the same because they both involve one `objc_msgSend()`: `image.size` is a method call to get the size, and `image.CGImage` is a method call to get the `CGImageRef`. These are stored properties, so they are not expensive to fetch in any case.