# Aspect ratio in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, aspect-ratio

I got app which can add photo from camera or gallery. After adding each photo showes in `UIImageView`. But they show with bad aspect ratio. Photoes are extended on `UIImageView's` size.

How can i show photoes with their real aspect ration?

UPD and what about small pictures? if user will add really small picture, this picture will resize on all area of `UIImageView`. How show this pictures in real size?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Doing `myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` is one option.

But it isn't enough because it changes the aspect ratio of the image, but it doesn't change the source image.

The only way to do that is to use the `UIGraphicsImageContext` as explained there:
[Resize UIImage with aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Who's Zhen? Did you just copy it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6689788/1048331

Comment: Copycat with 30k reputation!