# How to increase area that allows tapping on tableviewcell image?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a tableview cell with a custom image in the imageview of the cell. However, sometimes if you tap on the image (a checkbox), it taps on the actual cell instead of the image. I want to make it so if you tap part of the cell around the image, the checkbox is checked instead of the actual cell. How would I do this?

This is some code..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
```

The image is a 28x28 image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to solve this is to increase the width of the cell's image view.

Comment: how exactly do you access that property? it seems to be a read only

Comment: wait would i just use cell.imageview.frame?

Comment: You should subclass the cell and override the layoutSubviews method. Inside the method, set imageView.frame to whatever value you wish.

Comment: Also, if you're using the Sensible TableView framework, you can just use cell actions instead of subclassing the cell.

Comment: are you sure you changed the frame in layoutSubviews?

Comment: ok well i changed the layoutsubview and made the frame of the imageview CGRectMake(0,0,60,40), but it seems like the image gets resized...how could i just make the area of tapping increase but not the image?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255618/aspect-ratio-in-uiimageview

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to create `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to `cell.contentView` using the same selector you are using for image tapping.

Comment: but how would i only get part of the content view?

Comment: lets say like a 60x40 rectangle?

Comment: you can subclass `UITableViewCell` and either set a bigger imageView size or leave it be, but add another `UIView` with the bigger size below it. Then add the gesture recognizer to it.  Another option would be to use `UIControl` instead of `UIView` and just handle on touch up inside event (no gesture recognizer)