# Is it possible to display an image in Core Graphics with an Aspect Fit resize?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

A CALayer can do it, and a UIImageView can do it. Can I directly display an image with aspect-fit with Core Graphics? The UIImage drawInRect does not allow me to set the resize mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the math yourself. For example:

```
// desired maximum width/height of your image
UIImage *image = self.imageToDraw;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 42, 42); // desired x/y coords, with maximum width/height

// calculate resize ratio, and apply to rect
CGFloat ratio = MIN(imageRect.size.width / image.size.width, imageRect.size.height / image.size.height);
imageRect.size.width = imageRect.size.width * ratio;
imageRect.size.height = imageRect.size.height * ratio;

// draw the image
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);
```

Alternatively, you can embed a `UIImageView` as a subview of your view, which gives you easy to use options for this. For similar ease of use but better performance, you can embed a layer containing the image in your view's layer. Either of these approaches would be worthy of a separate question, if you choose to go down that route.

Comment: Note that this code as-is becomes a fit, not aspect fit, depending on the image.

Answer (score 12):

If you're already linking **AVFoundation**, an aspect-fit function is provided in that framework:

[`CGRect AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(CGSize aspectRatio, CGRect boundingRect);`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009540)

For instance, to scale an image to fit:

```
UIImage *image = …;
CRect targetBounds = self.layer.bounds;
// fit the image, preserving its aspect ratio, into our target bounds
CGRect imageRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(image.size, 
                                                       targetBounds);

// draw the image
CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);
```

Comment: Agreed.  @PhilCalvin is a hero.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. It'll draw the image in whatever rect you pass. So just pass an aspect-fitted rect. Sure, you have to do a little bit of math yourself, but that's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

here's the solution

```
CGSize imageSize = yourImage.size;
CGSize viewSize = CGSizeMake(450, 340); // size in which you want to draw

float hfactor = imageSize.width / viewSize.width;
float vfactor = imageSize.height / viewSize.height;

float factor = fmax(hfactor, vfactor);

// Divide the size by the greater of the vertical or horizontal shrinkage factor
float newWidth = imageSize.width / factor;
float newHeight = imageSize.height / factor;

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(xOffset,yOffset, newWidth, newHeight);
[image drawInRect:newRect];
```

-- courtesy https://stackoverflow.com/a/1703210