# How to resize image with aspect ratio?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

this is my code:-

```
(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{        
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: hi what is your problem .... can u explain?

Comment: just want to resize my image with aspect ratio,like dont want to loose the orginal shape of image

Answer (score 1):

Use the category files from [this](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) site to resize UIImages:

Answer (score 0):

Look this Qus , may be helped you...

> [Resize UIImage with aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio)

Comment: but really doesnt understand that what is value,what is fmax function,so it is not helping me out :(

Comment: value is the variable , is using to store the source image

Comment: what kind of variable??and what about fmax?

Comment: Value is related to the source image and fmax is Math functions double pow ( double, double ) - power of. Exp : NSLog(@"res: %.f", fmax(5,10)); //result 10