# Image gets stretched when captured

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` with a size of `(144,130)` and the image size I am getting after capturing is `(720,960)`.

I have resized image with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here new size is `(144,130)` which I have given because it is the `imageview`s size. Even though the image is getting stretched.

What should I make changes so that image does not get stretched?

EDIT-1

```
UIImage *imageCapture = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
UIImage *finalImage = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(imageview.frame.size)];
```

as per the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)

EDIT-2

Image captured has size : {720, 960}

imageview.frame.size : {144, 130}

newSize : {97.5, 130}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

with resizing u have to maintain the aspect ratio. just match your view's aspect ratio with the actual image and there won't be any stretched image...

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop) could be useful for you

Comment: You've been faster :D +1 :)

Comment: According to the ans given in link, it is giving aspectFit effect.where image is cutting in the side edges of imageview

Comment: with this, you can resize maintaining the aspect ratio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio/1703210#1703210

Answer (score -1):

You have set the Imageview Property

```
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

and if you are using nib then set the imageview property in View section-> Mode -> Aspect Fit

There is no need to resize your image. It worked for me.

And though you want to resize the image you can have following image in UIImage category

```
- (UIImage *) scaleProportionalToSize: (CGSize)size
{
    float widthRatio = size.width/self.size.width;
    float heightRatio = size.height/self.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        size=CGSizeMake(self.size.width*heightRatio,self.size.height*heightRatio);
    } else {
        size=CGSizeMake(self.size.width*widthRatio,self.size.height*widthRatio);
    }

    return [self scaledToSize:size];
}

- (UIImage *)scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //[newImage autorelease];
    return newImage;
}
```

When you are resizing image to newSize you must take into account that, if you are resize width by suppose 10% then you must resize height by 10% only.

Comment: after drawInRect, aspect-fit wont make any difference as the image is already re-rendered with new dimensions.

Comment: With your code also I am getting the image in the center(not stretched) but with side edges cut. Is there anything with my Imageview size?

Comment: when you are providing size to scaleProportionalToSize method provide the width and height of imageview (bounds) it will show desired image.

Comment: Yes I did that but it is still giving the same issue.Please check edit

Comment: ok can you please provide the original image. So that i can check it out.