# UIImageView isn't showing completely on 3,5 screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm trying to show an UIImageView with images on my iPhone 4, but this doesn't appear completely. The bottom part is hidden...this is the result:

[image]

I have tryed with 0 constraints on left, right, top and bottom margins but no effect...
Also adding width to 320 but the height is allways 568px (4 inch screen height )

Is not an image aspect problem. I'm using Aspect FIll for this case and works good, but the imageView height is always 568px. If I resize manually the heigth to 480px the image is OK.

Thanks a lot! I don't know what can I do...

Comment: You actually need to set right autoResizing mask to resize your imageView when screen size changes.

Answer (score 3):

try to use this,

```
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]
```

Comment: Is not a Content Mode problem...the frame is allways 568px, this is the problem. If I resize the ImageView to 480px, the image is showed correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the aspect ratio of the image.

- If you are using storyboard follow this link to set aspect ratio
  [aspect-ratio-of-image](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-keep-aspect-ratio-of-image)
- Aspect ratio can be changed as described    in [Resize UIImage with
  aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703100/resize-uiimage-with-aspect-ratio)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is not a Content Mode problem...the frame is allways 568px, this is the problem. If I resize the ImageView to 480px, the image is showed correctly

Comment: Then you need to use autolayout option to adjust the size automatically to fit 4 inch and a 3.5 inch screen.

Comment: How? I have tryed with constraints (right, left, top ad bottom) but without effect...

Comment: From Menu Option 'Editior\PIN'
    Top Space to Superview,
    Leading Space to Superview
Try using these options.

Comment: In XCode storyboard you can check the size of ImageView for both 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen. You can be sure whether ImageView is having 568 px.

Answer (score 0):

Don't  set frame programatically , if you set 568px height, it will take for both 4inch and 3.5.
just drag and drop the image view in to storyboard view. from Xcode5 autoLayout is there. Adjust autolayout.
autolayout will automatically fit the frames.

[AutoLayout Apple Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html)

Comment: I'm using storyboard drag and drop! At the beginning all worked fine, and the ImageView resizes fine changing between 4 and 3,5, making the work good. But now when I try to change between screens sizes, the imageView is allways 568px...

Comment: use autolayout, check out apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html

Answer (score 0):

Delete the constraint which forces the height to 568px. And Add constraint for left, top, right, bottom, margins with value 0.

Answer (score 0):

you set autosizing

you select image then set like below imgae

```
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]
```

it working iphone 5 or 4

[image]

Comment: this screenshot from xcode 5 please see select icon in this image is blue color